# LibGit2 treebuilder multi level insertion

Tags: git, libgit2

I have a git treebuilder I'm trying to populate with blobs. So I'm trying to do some sort of sharding to make finding blobs by filename easier. The files are named by their ID, so suppose I have filenames 11, 15, 21 and I'm sharding them into folders of multiples of 10 rounded up. Then I have two folders: 20 and 30. (In reality we have millions of entries).

inside them:

```
20 -> 11, 15
30 -> 21
```

Okay so the code looks something like this:

```
 std::string shardName = roundUp(ID, multiple);

 shardTB = shardMap_[shardName];
 git_treebuilder_insert(NULL, shardTB, ID, &blobOID, GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB);

 git_oid shardOID;
 git_treebuilder_write(&shardOID, shardTB);
 git_treebuilder_insert(NULL, TopLevelTB, shardName, &shardOID, GIT_FILEMODE_TREE);
```

So we insert a blob into the shard treebuilder, write the tree, then insert that tree into some other treebuilder.

This runs very slowly (about 10x slower) as opposed to not using the shards. I can't really tell why this would be so much slower considering that we're writing about the same number of files. Maybe libgit2 is doing something internally when overwriting a tree within a treebuilder. Just wondering if anyone knows anything about it, ie why this is so much slower, and if there is any way of speeding it up.

My idea right now to work around this is to just keep the shard map around, and then when I make the actual commit, iterate through the map and add them all at at that point, but I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

Comment: I think that the problem actually is due to the fact that we need to write the same treebuilders over and over, each time adding a new blob to that shard. They end up getting bigger each time we add a blob to them, and we rewrite them every single time which must get slower as the treebuilders hold more blobs (we end up rewriting the same blobs many times). Doing my workaround described above might be my best bet.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways of letting libgit2 do a bunch of this work for you. The "traditional" method is doing what git does when you use `git add` and `git commit` which is by reading data into an index file and performing the modifications there.

With libgit2 you do not have to store this index datastructure in a file, but can treat it in-memory. The index has a cache so it knows not to rewrite trees which have not changed.

You can create a new index with [`git_index_new()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_new), read our old tree in with [`git_index_read_tree()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_read_tree), perform your modifications and write it back out with [`git_index_write_tree_to()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write_tree_to). This will avoid recreating trees for "directories" which have not been modified, and will only write them out once, which sounds like you are not doing in your solution.

This can be slow if you have a lot of entries, as we need to read in every single tree. If your updates are often limited in scope, you can use [`git_tree_create_updated()`](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/tree/git_tree_create_updated) and feed it in the modifications you want. This function only reads in the trees which are going to change as a result of the list of updates you provide. It's not as flexible as doing everything by hand, but it covers the most common cases.

Without more information about the overall architecture I don't know why it would be so much slower than not using the sharding, but in your comment

> I think that the problem actually is due to the fact that we need to write the same treebuilders over and over, each time adding a new blob to that shard

it sounds like you're performing O(n) updates instead of one, which would certainly explain it.

You also mention having "millions of entries" which suggests you're trying to use Git as a database. The best advice I have about that is not to do it but instead invest in using a database. While the Git system looks quite a bit like a database and contains things we call databases, it is a very bad general purpose database.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! I didn't know about the git index file so I'll try seeing how I could modify the code to use it, seems like it could really simplify things. You're right it's not ideal to use git as a database, but we are testing this out to see what it's limits are.